# Amazon AWS NoSuchFieldError Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The log is

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_NAME
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.auth.S3SignerProvider.getSigner(S3SignerProvider.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.ExecutionContext.getSigner(ExecutionContext.java:135)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor$ExecOneRequestParams.newSigner(AmazonHttpClient.java:1934)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1281)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5456)
```

I am trying to get list of buckets from AWS S3

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, we can't help you with only stack trace, please show us your code and more details about your configuration.